# Classic ASP and MySQL database - I want to add an age restriction on a form with if then and else statement. Is this possible?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, datediff

So I am working in a classic ASP environment with a MySQL database. I want to add in a query to a form so that it adds an age restriction of being at least 13 years old. Here's what I was attempting to throw into the code:

```
If DATEDIFF("yyyy",now(), Person_DateOfBirth) > 12 Then
    Response.write "You are over 12"
Else
    Response.write "You are under 12"
End if
```

I am attempting to use the Datediff attribute to limit the age result. The now() variable is set as the current date, the `Person_DateOfBirth` variable is the selection that they choose on the form. Then im attempting to write a response on the screen depending on the value from the diffdate.

When this code is inserted into the query, there is no response at all.

I need help rewriting this code so it functions correctly, or if someone has another resolution in Classic ASP, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `Person_DateOfBirth` defined and assigned a value? Is it in a valid date format? Try using `CDate` to cast it to a date object. Or `IsDate` to make sure it is a valid date.

Answer (score 1):

The code requires the [ASP Form Collection](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_form.asp) to access the "Person_DateOfBirth" variable submitted through the form.

**Example Code**

*default.asp*

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="submit.asp" method="post">
        My age is <input type="text" name="Person_DateOfBirth">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*submit.asp*

```
<%
If DATEDIFF("yyyy",now(), request.Form("Person_DateOfBirth")) > 12 Then
    Response.write "You are over 12"
Else
    Response.write "You are under 12"
End if
%>
```

Comment: Hi @jblackmon if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.